# Apache not working on DigitalOcean droplet transfer

Tags: mysql, apache, digital-ocean, lamp, droplet

I’ve recently created a DigitalOcean droplet from a transferred snapshot.

I thought that recreating a droplet would have kept the original stack LAMP so that it would have worked out of the box.
MySQL seems to be working after re-installation, but I am getting an error message from APACHE.
I’ve tried to reinstall Apache, unfortunately it didn’t resolve the issue.

This is the error message I am getting:

[image]

Note: The original datacenter was located in New York, but I enabled and created the new droplet in Toronto.

Edit to include the Apache error Log:

> [18-Jan-2022 18:09:01 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:
> Unable to load dynamic library 'grpc.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/grpc.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/grpc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory ),
> /usr/lib/php/20170718/grpc.so.so
> (/usr/lib/php/20170718/grpc.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

Anyone ever ran into this issue? Any suggestions on how to resolve this problem?

Any good documentation on a DigitalOcean droplet transfer would be appreciated.

Comment: Read the error message "The Apache error log may have more information"

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @danblack, I have edited the post to include the Apache  Error Log